# How to show data in multiple columns in report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

Requirement:

I have a table in DB as below:

```
COP_MASTER
-----------------
CopDuty CopName    
Duty1     Alpha1
Duty2     Alpha2
Duty1     Alpha3
Duty1     Alpha4
Duty2     Alpha5
```

Using *iReport* I need to prepare a report where the report looks like this:

```
CopDuty        CopName
Duty1          Alpha1 Aplpha3 Alpha4
Duty2          Alpha2 Aplha5
```

Here the list of CopNames grows horizontally (or in a simpler terms the columns are dynamic).

I have already tried using subReport and inside the subReport's detail band a List element where the PrintOrder for the list element is kept "Horizontal". But the list grows vertically and not horizontally.

Any advice or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Prepare an independent report with the copName as a field to be displayed.
2. Make the printOrder properties available in the report properties tab as "Horizontal"
3. Change the Columns value:n (where n>1)
4. Go the main report and add the subreport element with the choice "Just add the subreport element".
5. Go to the Properties tab of the subreport element do the following changes as below:

   Subreport Expression: $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"CopSubReportFileName.jasper"
   DataSourceExpression: new net.sf.jasperreportsengine.data.JRBeanCollectionDatasource($F{cops})
6. Here we have to note that if the "cops" is a BO associated in the "Duty" BO then the above solution is just fine. But if it is to be tested through DB conn directly then the "dutyId" must be passed as  report input parameter to the subreport for the corresponding copNames to be fetched and printed.